# PostgreSQL Logical Replication Lag

Tags: postgresql, replication, pg-logical

I am using `pglogical` extension for logical replication between a PostgreSQL version 10 and 13.

I have multiple databases in the primary which are replicating data to three databases in logical replica. In total I have `63` subscriptions from the logical replica.

However, recently, the replication from one of my databases has started lagging. Which is causing the WAL files to generate rapidly. The WAL files are being archived and removed from `pg_wal` directory but very slowly.

The replication slot is active and the changes are being replicated as well and the subscription status is `streaming`. But it is slow and lagging.

Currently the only change is that we are executing a read-only query which processes a lot of data and is running for a long time.

I don't see anything in the logs and everything looks normal and I don't know what to check next. Can the read-only queries be the reason?

Below is my configuration settings from `postgresql.conf` for logical replication.

Master Configuration:

```
max_replication_slots = 90   
max_logical_replication_workers = 90
max_worker_processes = 90
max_wal_senders = 90
wal_sender_timeout = 300s
```

Replica Configuration:

```
max_replication_slots = 90   
max_logical_replication_workers = 96
max_worker_processes = 96
max_wal_senders = 10
wal_receiver_timeout = 5min
```

Edit:

I see that the replication is happening for the mentioned slots but it is slow. It is not a network issue though. Would increasing the `max_wal_sender` help at this point?

Comment: On which end is the read-only transaction running?

Comment: 'The WAL files are being archived and removed from pg_wal directory but very slowly."  They can't be removed until the slot is satisfied.  The archival wouldn't matter if the problem is the slot.

Comment: @jjanes the read-only transaction is running in primary, I cancelled it but it did not help.
Also, it is not a slot problem as the LSN location changes and I can see that data is being replicated.

Comment: If the slot is lagging, how can it not be a slot problem?  Is the slot lagging but not by enough to explain the WAL? On the replica side, what is the load like?

Comment: I have three slots in same database, two of them are catching up normally. One is falling behind. The load is the same in logical replica for all three slots.

Comment: But how are you measuring the load to know they are all the same?  And what is the load absolutely, not compared to other things.  Is it saturating the CPU?  The disk (`wa`)?

Comment: @jjanes I had three slots in the db, I figured out from reviewing the logs the slot that was lagging, there was an Exclusive lock on one of the tables being replicated. The lock was cleared and it was catching up. It caught up it self. Thank you for the help!